# Exportar usando datatable com limitações

Tags: jquery-datatables

Estou utilizando datatable em um projeto e esta funcionando 100%.
O que eu preciso é que no momento de exportar pra PDF e excel eu não quero exportar as colunas na qual eu não permito sort e nem search, que não colunas na qual tenho botões e em certos momentos imagens.

`usando exporteOptions: { colums: []}` até da certo, mas queria utilizar conforme citei acima, pra que eu reutilize o código em outras páginas.

Meu código ta assim:

```
myTable = $('#dynamicTableDesc').dataTable({
                sAjaxSource: "/@controller/List",
                bServerSide: true,
                bPaginate: true,
                pageLength: 50,
                dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
                buttons: [
                    //{ extend: 'copy' },
                    //{ extend: 'csv' },
                    { extend: 'excel', title: '@Html.Raw(titulo)' },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5', title: '@Html.Raw(titulo)',
                        //orientation: 'landscape',
                        pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: [0, 1]
                        } 
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'print',
                        customize: function (win) {
                            $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                            $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');
                            $(win.document.body).find('table').addClass('compact').css('font-size', 'inherit');
                            $(win.document.body).find('table').find('th:last-child').remove();
                            $(win.document.body).find('table').find('td:last-child').remove();
                        }
                    }
                ],
                aoColumnDefs: [
                    { bSortable: false, aTargets: [-1] },
                    { bSearchable: false, aTargets: [-1] },
                    {
                        mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                            var id = data;
                            var html = "<div class='ibox-tools'>";
                            html += "<a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#' aria-expanded='false'><i class='fa fa-ellipsis-h'></i></a><ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-user'>";
                            html += "<li><a href='/@controller/Details/" + id + "' title='Visualizar' class='detalhes @classDetails'> Visualizar</a></li>";
                                html += "<li><a href='/@controller/Edit/" + id + "?&ex=1' title='Alterar' class='alterar @classEdit'> Alterar</a></li>";
                                html += "<li><a href='javascript:;' title='Deletar' class='deletar @classDel' data-rel='" + id + "," + row[0].replace(",", "") + ",@controller,Del'> Deletar</a></li>";
                                html += "</ul></div>";
                                return html;
                            },
                            aTargets: [-1]
                        }
                ],
                fnRowCallback: function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                    $(nRow).attr("id", aData[aData.length - 1]);
                    return nRow;
                }

            });
```